# Hide DOM elements which do not have a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide all images which have no `data-web-src` attribute on 767px. I tried the following but I failed; how can I do that?

```js
$('#homepage-carousel .lazy_res').each(function(index, value) {
   var ws = $(window).width();
    var large = 1024;
    var medium = 767;
    var small = 0;
  if (ws <= medium) {
    $(this).not('[data-web-src]').hide();

  } else {
    $(this).not('[data-web-src]').show();
  }

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homepage-carousel">
  <img class="lazy_res" src="http://pre07.deviantart.net/338a/th/pre/i/2012/007/f/7/mapa_mundi_com_bandeiras___preto_by_plamber-d4leocd.jpg" alt="" />

  <img class="lazy_res" src="http://img05.deviantart.net/a6be/i/2013/099/8/9/helena_harper_by_plamber-d6125tx.jpg">
</div>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/awGBMz)

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikedeveloper/pen/pwVRzY

Comment: thank you it works only when resize the page how can we make specigif to work on default too?

Comment: I think it should work on page load also because I have triggered window resize event manually in it. If for some reason it's not working, you can keep the event handler code in a separate function and call that function on page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done with **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. No JavaScript required.

```css
/* Set page default styles and styles that should only
   be in effect for viewports under 767px wide here. */

img {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Apply the following CSS only to viewports wider than 767px */
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  /* Select all images except those with an attribute of: dat-web-src */
  img:not([data-web-src]) {
    display: none; /* Hide the matching elements */
  }
  
  /* Make any other CSS changes you like here */
  
  /* This class will only be applied to images when the media query
     is in effect. */
  img.someNewClass {
    /* Whatever you need here */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homepage-carousel">
  <img class="lazy_res" src="http://localhost:82/works/anitur/img/slider/1.jpg" alt="" />

  <img class="lazy_res" src="http://localhost:82/works/anitur/img/assets/mice-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: hey thank but I need to do with jquery because I will addclass in the same time

Comment: @ani_css You can simply add the class inside that media query - That's what media queries are for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your code within a function and then it can be called `onload` **and also `onresize`** to test it:

> see https://api.jquery.com/on/
>   **Description:** Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```js
function testit() {
  $("#homepage-carousel .lazy_res").each(function(index, value) {
    var ws = $(window).width();
    var large = 1024;
    var medium = 767;
    var small = 0;
    if (ws <= medium) {
    $(this).not('[data-web-src]').hide();

  } else {
    $(this).not('[data-web-src]').show();
  }
  });
}

$(window).on('resize load', testit );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
below 767px wide, you'll see nothing else here :), use the full page mode to test the snippet. then resize the window
<div id="homepage-carousel">  
<img class="lazy_res" src="http://pre07.deviantart.net/338a/th/pre/i/2012/007/f/7/mapa_mundi_com_bandeiras___preto_by_plamber-d4leocd.jpg" alt="" />

  <img class="lazy_res" src="http://img05.deviantart.net/a6be/i/2013/099/8/9/helena_harper_by_plamber-d6125tx.jpg">
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EXLZEN